# Send email to different port / redirecting port

Tags: email, email-server, dovecot, imap

I have an email server (Dovecot) and I want to emails be sent from other servers to a different IMAP port, because I can't use the ports 465 and 993

If someone could help me doing this, I would appreciate

Correction: actually i wrote it wrong, i want the server that's sending the email (e.g.: gmail) to my server use another port instead of 465/993 to my server receive the email

Comment: Email servers don't send email using IMAP, they send email using SMTP. IMAP is a "client" protocol used by email clients to retrieve and read email.

Comment: @joeqwerty actually i wrote it wrong, i want the server that's sending the email (e.g.: gmail) to my server use another port instead of 465/993 to my server receive the email

Comment: SMTP uses port 25. Not 465 or 993.

Answer (score 2):

That is just not possible. There is no mechanism that could tell other servers what port to use for SMTP.

Comment: ok thank you :)